# Django Rest Framework join 2 tables on non- foreign key fields

Tags: django, join, django-rest-framework

I am using Django for my website, and hence decided to use Django Rest Framework for building my REST APIs. However there is a common issue that i am facing when joining tables. If the join is defined on direct foreign keys, everything works fine. However when the joins are defined on non-direct foreign key fields, things go haywire.

Eg, i store stats for players in one table. (Stats table has 1 fk -> player)
i store participants in competitions in another table (This table has 2 fk -> player, competition)

If i retrieve stats information with player metadata, everything works fine. But i want to retrieve stats for all player in a given competition.

In SQL, i can join participant table with stats table on player id (common fk, but no direct link between the two tables as far as Django is concerned ie nothing is defined on the individual models of the 2 tables) and then filter on competition.

```
select a.* from Stats a inner join Participants b on a.player = b.player where competition = '%s'
```

How to replicate this using Django objects syntax? What i want to convert it to: something on the lines of,

```
Stats.objects.filter(stats__competition = %s)
```

So far i have been using raw SQL as the workaround. However i would like to move to a more permanent solution.

Any suggestions? I am open to moving to a different REST Framework (away from Django REST) if, the migration is straightforward and this join issue is resolved easily.

EDIT: adding minimalistic model:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='stats_player')
    ... (other fields)

class Participants(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='participant_player')
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition, related_name='participant_competition')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: 
`Stats.objects.filter(player__competitions = '%s')`
(it will return stats for players that attended a given competition)

We need your Django models declaration to be sure of the field names.
Here is a sample models that would work with this filter:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
  player = ForeignKey(Player, related_name='stats_player')
  ...

class Competition(models.Model):
   name = CharField(max_length=32)

class Player(models.Model):
   competitions = ManyToManyField(Competition)
```

Then you can write `Stats.objects.filter(player__competitions__name = '%s')`

You can optionally specify a Participant model for your many to many relation but you don't have to:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    competitions = ManyToManyField(Competition, through='Participant')

class Participant(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='participant_player')
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition, related_name='participant_competition')
    ... other fields
```

Comment: i have added minimalistic models.. your proposed solution does not work as player model does not have competition field...

Comment: Player model does not need a competitions field if you use a ManyToManyField. Your Participant table can be used by a ManyToManyField thanks through parameter. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

Comment: nice.. i think your revised answer should work.. but i am currently getting stuck in a cyclical import issue.. (thanks to splitting my models in various files to get the required schema name!)

Comment: so i shall try out your proposal and get back to you! as the cyclical import issue is proving to be very cumbersome to solve..

Comment: You can also use strings to define your ForeignKeys: `ForeignKey(Player)` can be written `ForeignKey('Player')` (so that you do not need to import Player model)

Comment: +2 for ForeignKey as string.. you are a saviour sir!